# How do I modify the value of an array of Bool in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of boolean as a state in my component. If it is false, I want to set it as true.

```
this.state = {
       checkedPos: []
}

handleChange(index, reaction) {
   if (!this.state.checkedPos[index])
   {
      this.state.checkedPos[index] = true;
      this.addReaction(reaction);
      this.forceUpdate();
   }
}
```

It works, but the only problem I encounter is that it show this warning:

> Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()

So I tried changing it and putting it like this:

```
this.setState({
 checkedPos[index]: true
})
```

But it does not compile at all.

Comment: Is `handleChange` bound to have component as `this` inside function ? Then follow @Tholle `s answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to `map` the previous array in your state. Since you should never modify your state without `setState` I will show you how you can use it in this solution :

```
handleChange(index) {
    this.setState(prev => ({
        checkedPos: prev.checkedPos.map((val, i) => !val && i === index ? true : val)
    }))
}
```

Here, `map` will change the value of your array elements to `true` only if the previous value was `false` and if the index is the same as the one provided. Otherwise, it returns the already existing value.

You can then use the second argument of `setState` to execute your function after your value has been updated :

```
handleChange(index) {
    this.setState(prev => ({
        checkedPos: prev.checkedPos.map((val, i) => !val && i === index ? true : val)
    }), () => {
        this.addReaction(reaction);
    })
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Iterating throught the array like you did (without binding function) makes the warning go away. I used the first example btw

Answer (score 2):

You can use the functional `setState` for this.

```
this.setstate((prevState) => ({
    const checkedPos = [...prevState.checkedPos];
    checkedPos[index] = true
    return { checkedPos };
}))
```

Comment: this will not change `checkedPos`, this will set a new property to state `checkedPos[index]` <-- whatever value of this will become key

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Will probably have to spread the whole array and overwrite the changed index