# How to replace array element by specific index number in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array of `[false,true,false,false,true]` I want to change these boolean values based on index number . I tried my best but didn't find a solution to resolve this issue. I want to be done this in react .

```
    this.setState({
       stateValue:[...array,array[0]=true]
   })
```

I tried with this solution but it can add value at the end of array

Comment: why don't you array[index] = true and call `setState`?

Comment: What is the rule for change?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I modify the value of an array of Bool in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55089592/how-do-i-modify-the-value-of-an-array-of-bool-in-react)

Comment: You can do this with [array map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp). Before learning react it is recommended that you have a solid understanding of advanced array methods such as map, filter, reduce & other ES6+ features.

Comment: using map to change a single value in an array is not an efficient solution, you don't need to iterate over an entire array in order to access or set a value

Comment: can you provide a more complete version of your code? please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  const newStateValue = [...prevState.stateValue]
  newStateValue[desired_index] = boolean_value
  return {
    ...prevState,
    stateValue: newStateValue,
  }
})
```

it's good practice when modifying state to do so in an immutable way, by first copying the data, manipulating the new copy and then setting that back into state.

using the `prevState => {}` callback to setState also helps to ensure the state changes get applied in the correct order if they occur in quick succession

Comment: actually, it not updating state

Comment: it's just sample code, obviously some of the variables are undefined / don't match up exactly how you would use it as just a drop in... did you change out the values with what you were trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I changed values but state is not updating actually

Answer (score -1):

Or this...

```
     var newArray = this.state.statevalue;
     newArray[i] = true;
     this.setState({stateValue: newArray});
```

Comment: This will also modify the current `this.state.stateValue` value... thats a bad practice